# torch code for three-dimensional multi-layer perception

Tags: torch

I want to transfer the data A (100, 196, 512) to data B(100, 1, 512).
It seems like a multi-layer perception. However, the function nn.Linear cannot be used for three dimension. How to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you want to put a batch of 100*512 vectors of dimension 196 through a network. To do this you need to essentially restate the problem as a batch of 1D problems, e.g.

```
model = nn.Sequential()
model:add( nn.Transpose({2},{3}) )
model:add( nn.View(100*512,196) )
model:add( nn.Linear(196,1) )
model:add( nn.View(100,512,196) )
model:add( nn.Transpose({2},{3}) )
```

This would be easier if your data was A(100,512,196), requiring only two nn.View modules.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this.